# How to iterate over a list and create sublist

Tags: python

I am iterating over a text file line by line that I made into a list. The text file is relatively small. I want to loop throughout the list and create sublist if there are two asteriks (in 2 lines) next to each other.

The text file separates sections on asterisks like this.

```
Header
*
Section 1 Header:
Content
Content
Content
*
*
Header
*
Section 2 Header:
Content
Content
Content
* 
*
```

```
TextFile_List = [line.strip() for line in open('TextFile.txt')]
for line in TextFile_List: line

output = []
for i in range(len(TextFile_List)):  #Iterates through all the lines in the list
    if TextFile_List[i]+TextFile_List[i+1]=="**":  #If * new line * are consecutive #Create sublist?/ Do something
        pass
```

When I run my code I get an error in this line

```
if TextFile_List[i]+TextFile_List[i+1]=="**":
```

I get a list index out of range, i think at the i+1 part.

Ideally, I would like to have each section be its own list. 
So the section 1 header, content, content, content would be its own list.

Like so,

```
List1 = ["Section 1 Header", "Content", "Content", "Content"]
List2 = ["Section 2 Header", "Content", "Content", "Content"]
etc...
```

Comment: Try with `for i in range(len(TextFile_List)-1)`. When it tries to do `TextFile_List[i+1]` for the last item, it is trying to find the next item and is giving error in process.

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: Along with index -1 error, if you have not stripped the lines off "\n"s, then you might want to check for `if TextFile_List[i]+TextFile_List[i+1]=="*\n*\n":`

Comment: I did strip off the lines using 
TextFile_List = [line.strip() for line in open('TestFile.txt')]
for line in TextFile_List: line

Comment: What do you do with the lines marked as just "Header", are they part of the output or not?

Comment: No they are not part of the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an off-by one error, when you reach the end of the list this will fail: `TextFile_List[i+1]`. Try this instead:

```
for i in range(len(TextFile_List) - 1):
```

Now, for the second part: this will be simpler if you have more control over the iteration indexes, here's a possible solution:

```
i = 0
output = []
sublist = []

while i < len(TextFile_List) - 1:
    line = TextFile_List[i]
    next_line = TextFile_List[i+1]
    if line == 'Header':
        i += 2
    elif line == '*' and next_line == '*':
        output.append(sublist)
        sublist = []
        i += 2
    else:
        sublist.append(line)
        i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the error, but doesn't answer the rest of the question on how to create a sublist.

Comment: thank you! i've been stuck on this for awhile. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of concatenating two lines and check for `**` is problematic (one line could be two asterisks and the other could be empty). Better is to check with something like:

```
if TextFile_List[i:i+2] == ["*", "*"]:
```

It also may be simpler to do this splitting before breaking into lines: for example this one-liner puts in `data` a list of sections where each section is a list of lines

```
data = [section.split("\n") for
        section in myfile.read().split("*\n*\n")]
```

Comment: Thanks, I did this but i'm still unsure of how to create a sublist I only got so far in my code